# Proof by induction (summation formula)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-writing, induction

I'm trying to prove by induction that:

$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^4 = \frac{1}{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$

This is how far I got:

Let $n = 1$

$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^4 = \frac{1}{30}(2)(3)(5) \implies 1 = 1$

End goal:

$\sum_{r=1}^{k+1} r^4 = \frac{1}{30}(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)(3(k+1)^2+3(k+1)-1)$

So,

$\sum_{r=1}^{k} r^4 + (k+1)^4 \\ = \frac{1}{30}k(k+1)(2k+1)(3k^2+3k-1) +(k+1)^4 \\ = \frac{1}{30}(k+1)[k(2k+1)(3k^2+3k-1) +30(k+1)^3]$

Now i'm stuck because I don't know where to go from here. I tried breaking all the brackets inside the big bracket but alas no luck in simplifying. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Neaten up your end goal $\frac{1}{30}(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)(k^2+9k+5)$ ... so you have formed the $(k+1)$ factor ... now expand the contents of the square bracket & see if you can form the $(k+2)$ factor ... keep going you are on the right track ...

Comment: Correction to previous comment ... quadratic factor should be $( \color{red}{3}k^2+9k+5)$.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply.

Comment: Have you expanded the content of the square bracket & got to ... $6k^4+39k^3+91k^2+89k+30$ ... ? You just need to verify that this does indeed factorise as required.

Comment: Hi yes I have this!

Comment: I'm almost there!

Comment: yay ... now factor ... $6k^4+39k^3+91k^2+89k+30=(k+2)(6k^3+27k^2+37k+15)$ ... & now the factor $(2k+3)$ ... & you are home & dry ! ... $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help!! Just i'm struggling on the last line:

$(k+2)(2k+3)(6k^2+18k+10)$

Comment: No, you are there ... divide the quadratic factor by $2$ ...$(\color{red}{2}k+3)$ !

Comment: I yes I took a common factor of 2 leaving me, $2(k+2)(2k+3)(3k^2+9k+5)$

Comment: Stuck now aha. Sorry!

Comment: Multiply it out ... $(k+2)(2k+3)(3k^2+9k+5)$ ... check it is equal to $6k^4+39k^3+91k^2+89k+30$ ... that $2$ is not needed ?

Comment: Ahhhh i was making a silly mistake! I lost the 3 from $k^2$. I've finally got it. Thank you so much Donald. i couldn't have done it without you!!